# Keep GNU screen attached to device

Tags: gnu-screen

I'm using `screen /dev/tty.usbmodemxxxx` to debug a physical device. An unavoidable part of my workflow disconnects and reconnects the device, causing `screen` to terminate; so I need to start it it up again.

Is there a way for me to say "keep `screen` alive listening on `/dev/tty.usbmodemxxxx` - just hang while it's not connected"?

Comment: Doesn't screen -r -d <screen name> work to reattach the screen ?

Comment: @AmitKumar "bad session name"

Comment: How do you start the screen ?  What do you see in "screen -ls"

Comment: @AmitKumar Starting with `screen /dev/tty.usbmodem` as I said in OP.

Answer (score 2):

Just a hack but you could write a wrapper script like:

```
#!/bin/sh
while [ TRUE ]
do
screen /dev/tty.usbmodemxxxx
read -p "connect again?"
done
```

and CTRL-c it when you want to stop.